# how to find my Google application credentials key.json

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I try to run Firebase Functions locally by following the [instruction here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator).

It mentioned these steps:

```
$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/key.json"

$ firebase experimental:functions:shell

OR

$ firebase serve --only functions
```

How can I find my `path/to/key.json`?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you followed the instructions on the page you linked to:

> To set up admin credentials for emulated functions (other than Cloud
>   Firestore and Realtime Database):
>
> - Open the Service Accounts pane of the Google Cloud Console.
> - Make sure that App Engine default service account is selected, and use the options menu at right to select Create key.
> - When prompted, select JSON for the key type, and click Create.
> - Set your Google default credentials to point to the downloaded key

Only you know the path of the JSON file you just downloaded from the console.  Put the full path to that file there.

Comment: There is no "options menu to the right" to create the key.

Comment: @ActionJackBarker If you think the linked page of instructions are no longer accurate, use the "Send feedback" button on the page to let the authors know.